# same record repeats in different pagination pages Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

This is very weird issue, but I see same record with same exact ID repeating on page 2 and page 5 of my returned results:

[image]

I am using Postgres as my database.

This is my view Class:

```
class SList(generics.ListAPIView):  # 100 pagination
    queryset = S.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SSerializer_short2
    name = 's-list'

    ordering_fields = (
        '-date_time',

    )

    permission_classes = (
        permissions.IsAdminUser,
    )

    filter_class = SFilter
```

also in my model I have the following class:

```
class Meta:
    indexes = [
        models.Index(fields=['symbol', 'interval', '-date_time']),
    ]
```

Comment: Does your `QuerySet` has been *sorted*?

Comment: Please post your queryset, if you're using `.annotate()` you might have to add `.distinct()`

Comment: just added my view and meta class, which indexes my database

Answer (score 0):

Try to SORT or use DISTINCT for your query

Comment: @Drakes95 with your hint, I changed my queryset to S.objects.all().order_by('-date_time') and it works. Please add this to your answer and I would tag it as correct answer. Thank!